# QAction is a special GUI related class, can it be connected to slots?

Tags: qt

I was wondering if somebody could clarify the following for me. I'm about to sit a test in relation to Qt and the sample questions are rather ambiguous. One of the questions are as follows:

**QAction is a special GUI related class in Qt. About QAction instances, we can 
correctly say that:**

- a. QAction istances are equivalent to slots.
- b. QAction instances can be connected to slots.
- c. QAction instances trigger GUI events automatically.

Am I right in thinking QAction's can actually be connected to slots? And that B is the correct answer?

Comment: [`QAction`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qaction.html#details) documentation explains pretty well what it is and what it can do.

Comment: I guess it's B then, thanks.

Comment: I would recommend B, since they act as a kind of proxy between user action and the slot, which ``they are connected to``

Answer (score 2):

`QAction` is just a class. It acts exactly like other `QObject` classes when it comes to signals and slots. All "a", "b" and "c" statements are wrong. `QAction` instance is not a slot and cannot be connected to a slot. "Connection" is defined only between instances' signals and slots, not instances themselves. The truth is that `QAction` provides `triggered` signal that can be connected to a slot.

Also it seems that you may be confused by [slots auto-connection](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdesigner/designer-using-a-ui-file.html#widgets-and-dialogs-with-auto-connect). You can create a slot named `on_<action_name>_triggered` and it will be automatically connected to the corresponding action. But this feature works with any QObject-derived classes, not only QAction.

It's hard to understand what you mean by "GUI events". QAction is not a widget. It doesn't operate GUI directly. Any GUI events are processed by the used widget (e.g. QMenu). Also note that events are not signals. When you use QAction, you generally don't need to think about events.